Using ARKit for Indoor Distance Tracking in an iOS App: Feasibility and Potential Pitfalls
I am developing an iOS app to calculate the distance a person moves within their home. The goal is to track a person's movement for 3-4 minutes and provide live feedback on the distance traveled in the x and y directions.
Initially, I considered using GPS for this purpose, but I realized that GPS has a large error margin and isn't suitable for indoor distance tracking. Therefore, I'm exploring the possibility of using ARKit (or potentially VRKit) to achieve this.
My questions are:

Is it feasible to use ARKit for accurately tracking the distance moved indoors?
What markers or tools within ARKit can assist in providing accurate movement data?
Are there any existing examples or best practices for implementing this type of functionality?
What potential pitfalls or sources of error should I be aware of when using ARKit for indoor distance tracking? what guidance can i show to my user on the app so that this system works accurately.

